# Post To Chatter Group with Apex

Tags: apex, chatter

I want to post a message to a specific Chatter group using Apex.

If I understand it correctly, Chatter groups are stored in the CollaborationGroup object.

Therefore, I want to do something like:

```
public static void postToChatter(String chatterGroupId) {
    if(chatterGroupId instanceof Id) {
        CollaborationGroup chatterGroup = [select Id, Name from CollaborationGroup where id = :chatterGroupId];
        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.Title = 'My Title';
        post.Body = 'My message body';
        post.ParentId = chatterGroup.Id;
        insert post;
    }
}
```

I see that the parent could be any [ActorWithId](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm#capi_actorWithIdOutput) class. One of its subclasses is [ChatterGroup](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_outputs.htm#capi_chatter_group_output), but this class is abstract. It doesn't seem it makes sense (or is possible) to instantiate its implementations.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you use this? I have code very similar to this in production in several orgs.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking I had to instantiate a Chatter group and pass it to post.Parent. Then I realized the Id might be enough (and updated the question). I still have to test it, but thanks for letting me know you have some like this working.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [ConnectAPI](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_postFeedItem.htm):

```
ConnectApi.FeedItem fi = ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, '0F9L00000004ahL', 'My Test Post');
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. What is the advantage of doing it this way 2. where are you telling it which chatter group to post to

Comment: This is the Chatter Group Id: '0F9L00000004ahL' (see the docs for more explanation of each param)

For a simple post, there is no real benefit - where it becomes more important is when you want to do more complex posts e.g. include @mentions, rich text etc. At that point, you have to use ConnectAPI - so for consistency, I tend to use ConnectAPI even for simple posts, so I am not switching between styles. They just released a new helper class to make messageSegments (the core framework for complex posts) easier to use - you can see more explanation here (http://goo.gl/xKgNlK)

Comment: After trying this code I got this error: "Method was removed after version 31.0: postFeedItem"..

Comment: So for orgs with a higher API version the 'insert' approach is better.. See [here](https://gist.github.com/yoni-g/dd1663f050ea99204d41c899abcde276) for example.